# How do I assign specific data points in an array to a new array?

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to learn how to script/program in mathematica and I am retyping some simple C and FORTRAN programs into Mathematica as a way to learn.  I am writing a Monte Carlo code to calculate the value of pi.  In the method attached a 10000x2 dimensional array is created using table with values ranging from 0 to 1.  The magnitude of each row of the array is determined inside a For loop and if it is greater than 0 it is rejected and if it is less it is used in the running tally that is divided by the total number of points and then multiplied by 4 to give an estimate of pi.  On top of calculating pi, I would like to create two more arrays to use in a list plot.  In a second array I would like to store values of the first array that met the rejection criteria and in third array I would like to store values that were rejected, so I can plot the rejected points as red and the accepted points as blue.  However, no matter what I try Mathematica will not seem to let me transfer points from the first array titled "vector".  I am attaching the current code to this question that effectively calculates the estimate of pi.  If anyone can show me how to transfer the rejected points to another array as determined inside the For loop I would be very grateful.

`[counter, samples, a, vector, tally, pi, tally2]
counter = 1; samples = 10000; 
tally = 1; a := Random[Real, {0, 1}];
Timing[vector = Table[a, {i, samples}, {j, 2}]; 
 For[i = 1, i <= samples, 
  i++, {If[Norm[vector[[i]]] < 1, tally++, ""]}];
 pi = (tally/samples)*4 // N]`
`

Comment: Please take a look at this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/193, and this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18/193. You're using the wrong paradigms ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

Generate your 2D points:

```
arr = RandomReal[1, {100000, 2}];
```

From there `Select` points that fall within a quarter of a circle:

```
cir = Select[arr, Norm[#] < 1 &];
```

Now compute `Pi`

```
N[4 Length[cir]/Length[arr]]
```

This gives:

```
3.14292
```

As you increase the number of points, your approximation of `Pi` will be better.

You can even plot the two regions as follows:

```
Graphics[{If[Norm[#] < 1, Red, Darker[Green]], Point[#]} & /@ arr]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you, I was not even aware that the Select function even existed much less how to use it.  I also did not even think to use the length function.  Your comment was a big help in my learning process, thank you.

Comment: @Jon. Glad I could help. Note that you can up vote an answer if you like it and you can also select one of the answers that you feel was most helpful to you. Welcome to *Mathematica* stackexchange.

Comment: I will do that.  Would you mind also helping solve a minor mystery for me?  I know the general theory behind the # and & symbols but there are a few things perplexing me in your example.  As I understand it the code will reference a # to a & symbol and the variable to the right of the & symbol.  However, in your second line of code there is nothing to the right of the & symbol.  Also in the last line there is a /@ to the right of it.  How are these symbols working?

Comment: Also it will not let me add a like to your comment, I have to have a 15 reputation in order for the web site to allow this.

Comment: @Jon see this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616

Answer (score 0):

Just for a minor alternative:

```
arr = RandomReal[1, {100000, 2}];
g = GatherBy[arr, Norm@# < 1 &];
pi = 4. #1/(#1 + #2) & @@ (Length /@ g)
ListPlot[g, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}, AspectRatio->1,Frame->True![\]][1]
```

where`pi` is $\pi$ approximation

[image]